# Add multiple fields to django form

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am new to django and I'm making food recipe app. I want the users to be  able to add their own recipe.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Recipe(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.recipe_name

    recipe_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    prep_time = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    difficulty = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    instructions_url = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

class Ingredients(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.ingredients

    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ingredients = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

views.py

```
class RecipeCreate(CreateView):
    model = Recipe
    fields = ['recipe_name', 'category', 'image', 'prep_time', 'difficulty', 'instructions_url']
```

At the moment my form display the fields only from my "class Recipe", but what i want is to have Ingredient field with option to add additional fields. Do you have any suggestions how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: See my answer below. Note: I'd change the `Ingredients` model to be singular. Each `ingredient` its own db row. Or do you really want to save all the ingredients of a recipe as a big long `CharField`?

Answer (score 0):

It's going to be difficult to do that with the generic `CreateView` which is meant to create just one instance of a model.

What you want is a view (you could use the generic Django `View`) with a form (`ModelForm`) for your `Recipe` and a `formset` (see [Django formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/formsets/)) for multiple `Ingredients` forms. In your `View`'s `post` method you then validate all the forms and save the data.

In your HTML, you'll need to create additional fields dynamically using javascript and update the number of formsets accordingly (in the formset's [management form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform))